# Value in Hashmap not totaling correct number. iterated 1000 times but total values equal 1021

Tags: java, hashmap

```
public void Randomize(Integer num){
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0; i <= num; i++){
        int random = (int)(Math.random()* (21 - 1)) + 1;
        if(!map.containsKey(random)){
            map.put(random, 1);
        }
        int temp = map.get(random);
        temp++;
        map.put(random, temp);
    }
```

did sout to display map in terminal. sum of all values totals 1021 and not 1000
   }

Comment: If the number is not in the map, you put 1 into it, read the 1 back, and add an other 1? You are off by 20. The other off-by-one is `i <= num`.

Comment: Im attempting to increment each time a number is repeated. My goal was that if the number did not exist as a key then to add it and initialize its value as 1. then if it did exist to increment the key by 1. But I think i get what you're saying, I'll try and mess with it. Thanks

Comment: Either initialize with 0, or put the increment into the else branch. Or consider using `map.merge(random, 1, (a , b) -> a + b);`